# Multiple Pseudo-classes?

Tags: html, css

I have searched the posts, but have not found the solution I'm looking for...

I attempted chaining these pseudo-classes(:first-child & :hover), but it didn't work out.  I could have sworn that this has worked for me in the past, but I'm getting no results.  I'm attempting a pure CSS solution.  Any help would be much appreciated.  Thanks!

```
#main_nav ul li:first-child a:hover { color: green; }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i used your code exactly and it works fine for me, so i'm guessing that you either misspelt your ID or you haven't selected it properly or its being overridden somewhere else.

Comment: Thanks for checking,  dragonvsphoenix.  I will look around in the code and see if there are any conflicts.

Comment: also, i only checked in firefox, maybe its your browser? EDIT: works for me in IE and chrome aswell

Comment: There was a conflict elsewhere in the code as you suspected, dragonvsphoenix.  Good call!  I adjusted it and browser-checked, and all is well.  Thanx again!